# From Joomla 3 (or 3.4) will there be a one-click update?

Tags: update, upgrade

I have one clear question:

Will updating from Joomla 3.4 to any future versions **including 3.4.x to 3.5.x *(((to 4.x.y and ANY future versions)))*** have ONE-CLICK UPGRADES?

Or 3.x.y to 4.x.y will still have hard instructions like [updating from 2.5 to 3](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_2.5_to_3.x_Step_by_Step_Migration) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla *as I understand* are no longer doing the normal process like so:

- 2.5 (Long Term)
- 3.0 (Short Term)
- 3.5 (Long Term)
- 4.0 (Short Term)
- 4.5 (Long Term)

Instead they will me using the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) process.

The [Joomla Roadmap](http://developer.joomla.org/cms/roadmap.html) shows you the upcoming versions:

So from now on, it will be as follows:

- **Major updates (e.g 4.0)** - Big API changes. A migration process will be required.
- **Minor updates (e.g 3.5, 3.6)** - 1 click update
- **Patch updates (e.g 3.5.1, 3.5.2)** - 1 click update

So basically every Joomla 3.x version will be a 1-click update, however, I would still suggest looking through the changelog provided for each minor release, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Anything from 3.x to any other 3.x version will indeed be a 1 click updated as @Lodder says. 3.x to 4.x technically will also be a one click upgrade. BUT that assumes that all your templates and extensions and 3.x and 4.x compatible (which given it *might* involve complex API changes is NOT guaranteed in any way. That was the same as the 2.5 to 3.x if you remember)